# How to improve battery life on MBP 2015?

Tags: macbook, power, battery, apple

I really like elementary os, i installed it on my 15" MBP 2015 -- however the battery life is pretty bad. I get about 3 hours maximum if i'm lucky -- this is much less than the 10 hours i'm used to on this laptop.

Does anyone have any MBP specific tips for improving battery life? I've read a few articles about setting up TLP, which i did, but it hasn't really helped.

EDIT: the most power-hungry process (according to power-top is radeon (my graphics card))

`3.9 ms/s 57.8 Interrupt [37] radeon`

Thanks!